# TFS workitemsare table

Tags: tfs

Does anyone know what this field [Not a Field] means in TFS WorkItemsAre table? I am trying to understand the schema and this is not making any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the operational datastore is not supported as in every release we will make break changes. You'd rather move to the TFS API or the TFS Warehouse database to get the data your are interested in.

What is it that you are after?

Comment: I am trying to create work items by directly inserting into the table as part of a sync process between two systems. I am using SSIS to achieve this. TFS API is an option I am definitely considering.